# ReactiveMongo custom BSONDocument{ Reader, Writer }

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I'm new with ReactiveMongo and I want to create a custom document reader/writer for one object but I'm getting this error

```
type mismatch;  found   :
reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocumentReader[reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocument]
required:
reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocumentReader[db.DataBase.Estudiante]  Note:
implicit object EstudianteReader is not applicable here because it
comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
```

This is my code and is based in this [example](https://github.com/sgodbillon/reactivemongo-demo-app) I found in reactivemongo's official webpage.

```
package db

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

import reactivemongo.api._
import reactivemongo.bson._

object DataBase {

  //Driver para la conexion
  val driver = new MongoDriver

  //Conexion con mongoDB
  val connection = driver.connection(List("localhost"))

  //Conexion con la base de datos AMDB
  val db = connection("reactive")

  //Colección domainNames que se encuentra en la base de datos AMDB
  val collection = db("estudiantes")

  def findAllDomainNames() = {

    val query = BSONDocument()
    collection.find(query).cursor[Estudiante]
    //.cursor[BSONDocument].collect[List]()
  }

case class Estudiante(id: Option[BSONObjectID], nombre: String, apellidos: String, edad: Int)

  object Estudiante {

    implicit object EstudianteWriter extends BSONDocumentWriter[Estudiante] {
      def write(estudiante: Estudiante): BSONDocument = {
        BSONDocument(
          "_id" -> estudiante.id.getOrElse(BSONObjectID.generate),
          "nombre" -> estudiante.nombre,
          "appellidos" -> estudiante.apellidos,
          "edad" -> estudiante.edad.toString)
      }
    }

    implicit object EstudianteReader extends BSONDocumentReader[Estudiante] {
      def read(doc: BSONDocument): Estudiante = {
        Estudiante(
          doc.getAs[BSONObjectID]("_id"),
          doc.getAs[String]("nombre").get,
          doc.getAs[String]("appellidos").get,
          doc.getAs[Int]("edad").get)
      }
    }

  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(findAllDomainNames);
  }
}
```

What is missing/wrong?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the declaration of the object `Estudiante` above `DataBase` and add an import in the scope of `DataBase`:

```
import Estudiante._
```